# Plotting a number line in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, intervals

I would like to plot a simple interval on the number line in Mathematica.  How do I do this?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you want? Do you want open and closed dots or open parentheses and closed brackets? Do you want just the relevant numbers or a range of numbers in between the important ones?

Comment: The demonstration [Number Line Solutions to Absolute Value Equations and Inequalities](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/NumberLineSolutionsToAbsoluteValueEquationsAndInequalities/) does a good job of drawing a simple interval.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another attempt that draws number lines with the more conventional white and black circles, although any graphics element that you want can be easily swapped out.

It relies on `LogicalExpand[Simplify@Reduce[expr, x]]` and `Sort` to get the expression into something resembling a canonical form that the replacement rules can work on. This is not extensively tested and probably a little fragile. For example if the given `expr` reduces to `True` or `False`, my code does not die gracefully.

```
numLine[expr_, x_Symbol:x, range:{_, _}:{Null, Null}, 
  Optional[hs:_?NumericQ, 1/30], opts:OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{le = {LogicalExpand[Simplify@Reduce[expr, x]]} /. Or -> List,
   max, min, len, ints = {}, h, disk, hArrow, lt = Less|LessEqual, gt = Greater|GreaterEqual},
  If[TrueQ@MatchQ[range, {a_, b_} /; a < b],
   {min, max} = range,
   {min, max} = Through[{Min, Max}@Cases[le, _?NumericQ, \[Infinity]]]];
  len =Max[{max - min, 1}]; h = len hs;
  hArrow[{x1_, x2_}, head1_, head2_] := {{Thick, Line[{{x1, h}, {x2, h}}]},
                                         Tooltip[head1, x1], Tooltip[head2, x2]};
  disk[a_, ltgt_] := {EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], 
    Switch[ltgt, Less | Greater, White, LessEqual | GreaterEqual, Black], 
    Disk[{a, h}, h]};
  With[{p = Position[le, And[_, _]]}, 
       ints = Extract[le, p] /. And -> (SortBy[And[##], First] &); 
       le = Delete[le, p]];   
  ints = ints /. (l1 : lt)[a_, x] && (l2 : lt)[x, b_] :> 
     hArrow[{a, b}, disk[a, l1], disk[b, l2]];
  le = le /. {(*_Unequal|True|False:>Null,*)
     (l : lt)[x, a_] :> (min = min - .3 len; 
       hArrow[{a, min}, disk[a, l], 
        Polygon[{{min, 0}, {min, 2 h}, {min - Sqrt[3] h, h}}]]),
     (g : gt)[x, a_] :> (max = max + .3 len; 
       hArrow[{a, max}, disk[a, g], 
        Polygon[{{max, 0}, {max, 2 h}, {max + Sqrt[3] h, h}}]])};
  Graphics[{ints, le}, opts, Axes -> {True, False}, 
   PlotRange -> {{min - .1 len, max + .1 len}, {-h, 3 h}},
   GridLines -> Dynamic[{{#, Gray}} & /@ MousePosition[
                           {"Graphics", Graphics}, None]], 
   Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
  ]
```

(Note: I had originally tried to use `Arrow` and `Arrowheads` to draw the lines - but since `Arrowheads` automatically rescales the arrow heads with respect to the width of the encompassing graphics, it gave me too many headaches.)

OK, some examples:

```
numLine[0 < x], 
numLine[0 > x]
numLine[0 < x <= 1, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
numLine[0 < x <= 1 || x > 2, Ticks -> {{0, 1, 2}}]
```

[image]

```
numLine[x <= 1 && x != 0, Ticks -> {{0, 1}}]
```

[image]

```
GraphicsColumn[{
  numLine[0 < x <= 1 || x >= 2 || x < 0],
  numLine[0 < x <= 1 || x >= 2 || x <= 0, x, {0, 2}]
  }]
```

[image]

**Edit:**  Let's compare the above to the output of [Wolfram|Alpha](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WolframAlpha.html)

```
WolframAlpha["0 < x <= 1 or x >= 2 or x < 0", {{"NumberLine", 1}, "Content"}]
WolframAlpha["0 < x <= 1 or x >= 2 or x <= 0", {{"NumberLine", 1}, "Content"}]
```

[image: output of the above]

Note (when viewing the above in a Mathematica session or the W|A website) the fancy tooltips on the important points and the gray, dynamic grid lines. I've stolen these ideas and incorporated them into the edited `numLine[]` code above.

The output from `WolframAlpha` is not quite a normal `Graphics` object, so it's hard to modify its `Options` or combine using `Show`. To see the various numberline objects that Wolfram|Alpha can return, run `WolframAlpha["x>0", {{"NumberLine"}}]` - "Content", "Cell" and "Input" all return basically the same object. Anyway, to get a graphics object from

```
wa = WolframAlpha["x>0", {{"NumberLine", 1}, "Content"}]
```

you can, for example, run

```
Graphics@@First@Cases[wa, GraphicsBox[__], Infinity, 1]
```

Then we can modify the graphics objects and combine them in a grid to get

[image: aligned]

Comment: Thanks! I also remembered last night that Wolfram|Alpha can plot number lines; e.g. [0<x<=1 or x>2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Cx%3C%3D1+or+x%3E2)

Comment: Neat, but:)  WHY WHY WHY do I get to download a Mathematica notebook of the output if it is not usable?

Answer (score 10):

For plotting  open or closed intervals you could do something like:

```
intPlot[ss_, {s_, e_}, ee_] := Graphics[{Red, Thickness[.01],
   Text[Style[ss, Large, Red, Bold], {s, 0}],
   Text[Style[ee, Large, Red, Bold], {e, 0}],
   Line[{{s, 0}, {e, 0}}]},
  Axes -> {True, False},
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Thin, Blue, 12],
  PlotRange -> {{ s - .2 Abs@(s - e), e + .2 Abs@(s - e)}, {0, 0}},
  AspectRatio -> .1]

intPlot["[", {3, 4}, ")"]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Following is the nice extension done by @Simon, probably spoiled by me again trying to solve the overlapping intervals issue.

```
intPlot[ss_, {s_, e_}, ee_] := intPlot[{{ss, {s, e}, ee}}]
intPlot[ints : {{_String, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, _String} ..}] :=
 Module[{i = -1, c = ColorData[3, "ColorList"]},
  With[
   {min = Min[ints[[All, 2, 1]]], max = Max[ints[[All, 2, 2]]]},
   Graphics[Table[
     With[{ss = int[[1]], s = int[[2, 1]], e = int[[2, 2]], ee = int[[3]]}, 
       {c[[++i + 1]], Thickness[.01],
       Text[Style[ss, Large, c[[i + 1]], Bold], {s, i}], 
       Text[Style[ee, Large, c[[i + 1]], Bold], {e, i}],
       Line[{{s, i}, {e, i}}]}], {int, ints}], 
    Axes -> {True, False}, 
    AxesStyle -> Directive[Thin, Blue, 12], 
    PlotRange -> {{min - .2 Abs@(min - max), max + .2 Abs@(min - max)}, {0, ++i}}, 
    AspectRatio -> .2]]]

(*Examples*)

intPlot["[", {3, 4}, ")"]
intPlot[{{"(", {1, 2}, ")"}, {"[", {1.5, 4}, ")"}, 
        {"[", {2.5, 7}, ")"}, {"[", {1.5, 4}, ")"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but do you mind if I edit the above to generalize for multiple intervals?

Comment: @Simon Overlapping intervals will spoil the plot. I think another visualization strategy is needed for that :(

Comment: True. I only tested my modification of your code on non-overlapping intervals. You'd need to manually simplify/reduce first...

Comment: @Simon Anyway, If you consider it an improvement, feel free to edit my answer or post a new one!

Comment: On reflection, it ruins the clarity of your answer. [Here's](http://pastebin.com/Gc7j2bMT) my extension of your code on pastebin.

Comment: @Simon Thanks! Extended again and posted as an Edit

Answer (score 6):

Here's an ugly solution using `RegionPlot`. Open limits are represented using dotted lines and closed limits with full lines

```
numRegion[expr_, var_Symbol:x, range:{xmin_, xmax_}:{0, 0}, opts:OptionsPattern[]] :=
            Module[{le=LogicalExpand[Reduce[expr,var,Reals]],
                    y, opendots, closeddots, max, min, len},
 opendots =   Cases[Flatten[le/.And|Or->List], n_<var|n_>var|var<n_|var>n_:>n];
 closeddots = Cases[Flatten[le/.And|Or->List], n_<=var|n_>=var|var<=n_|var>=n_:>n];
 {max, min} = If[TrueQ[xmin < xmax], {xmin, xmax}, 
                 {Max, Min}@Cases[le, _?NumericQ, Infinity] // Through];
 len = max - min;
 RegionPlot[le && -1 < y < 1, {var, min-len/10, max+len/10}, {y, -1, 1},
            Epilog -> {Thick, Red, Line[{{#,1},{#,-1}}]&/@closeddots,
                       Dotted, Line[{{#,1},{#,-1}}]&/@opendots},
            Axes -> {True,False}, Frame->False, AspectRatio->.05, opts]]
```

An example reducing an absolute value:

```
numRegion[Abs[x] < 2]
```

[image: example 1]

Can use any variable:

```
numRegion[0 < y <= 1 || y >= 2, y]
```

[image: example 2]

`Reduce`s extraneous inequalities, compare the following:

```
GraphicsColumn[{numRegion[0 < x <= 1 || x >= 2 || x < 0],
                numRegion[0 < x <= 1 || x >= 2 || x <= 0, x, {0, 2}]}]
```

[image: example 3]

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Mathematica 10, there is [`NumberLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberLinePlot.html) available.

Answer (score 1):

The previous ugly solution has helped me to develop the InequalityPlot function to solve and plotting inequalities in two variables.

```
InequalityPlot[ineq_, {x_Symbol, xmin_, xmax_},{y_Symbol, ymin_, ymax_},
  opts : OptionsPattern[Join[Options[ContourPlot],
    Options[RegionPlot], {CurvesColor -> RGBColor[1, .4, .2]}]]] :=
 Module[{le = LogicalExpand[ineq], opencurves, closedcurves, curves},
  opencurves = Cases[Flatten[{le /. And | Or -> List}],
   lexp_ < rexp_ | lexp_ > rexp_ | lexp_ < rexp_ | lexpr_ > rexp_ :>
    {lexp == rexp, Dashing[Medium]}];
  closedcurves = Cases[Flatten[{le /. And | Or -> List}],
   lexp_ <= rexp_ | lexp_ >= rexp_ | lexp_ <= rexp_ | lexp_ >= rexp_ :>
    {lexp == rexp, Dashing[None]}];
  curves = Join[opencurves, closedcurves];
  Show[  RegionPlot[ineq, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax},
    BoundaryStyle -> None,
    Evaluate[Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[RegionPlot]]]],
   ContourPlot[First[#] // Evaluate, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax},
      ContourStyle -> Directive[OptionValue[CurvesColor], Last[#]],
      Evaluate[Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts},
         Options[ContourPlot]]]] & /@ curves  ]
 ]
```

Here are two examples:

```
InequalityPlot[0.5 <= x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
InequalityPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 0.5 && x + y <= 0.5,{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Do a regular `Plot`, and set `Axes -> {True, False}` (and hide the bounding box if one exists, which one usually does not). Adjust image size or aspect ratio as appropriate.

e.g.

```
Plot[
    Piecewise[{
        {0, And[0<x, x<1]}
    }],
    {x,-1,2},
    Axes -> {True, False}        
]
```

You can use `Show` to combine this with an imagine of open-and-closed dots.

There is a small chance you may have to pass in `Indeterminate` or some other special value as the second argument to `Piecewise` (or else it defaults to 0), if you do not properly set your line width or similar plotting styles; or, alternatively but more assuredly, set the value to 999 and `PlotRange -> {{-1,2},{-.1,.1}}`.

Comment: Your code does not work. You are missing a plot domain, and your Piecewise is equivalent to the function f(x)=0...

Comment: @Simon: I warned about this in my answer. Thanks for the mention about the plot domain though.