# How do I get the crosshair behavior of Wolfram|Alpha 2D graphics in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

When the mouse cursor is over a 2D plot in Wolfram|Alpha, a pair of grey lines appear that help you read the coordinates off the x and y axes[.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797651/plotting-a-number-line-in-mathematica/6806152#6806152)
[For example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20Ai%28x%29), I have the mouse over one of the turning points in the following plot of the Airy function.

[image: Web]

The above can also be obtained inside Mathematica using

```
WolframAlpha["Plot Ai(x)", {{"Plot", 1}, "Content"}]
```

[image: Nb]

which has the added advantage of some sort of locator showing the coordinates[.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7221397/421225)

---

How can I emulate such behavior in a normal Mathematica graphics/plot?

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but just in case you don't: right click on the graphics & choose "get coordinates".  You can even mark points by clicking, and then copy them.  This has been available since pre-6 versions. (Assuming your aim was to read off coordinates interactively.)

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks, I did know that, but it's worth pointing out again! I was mainly looking to emulate the W|A code. I have my own code (I'll post later) that does most of it, but, among other things, it doesn't handle multiple graphs as well as the W|A code.

Comment: Just use `InputForm` on the result from `WolframAlpha[..]`...

Comment: @Brett: That's where I stole the idea for dynamic `GridLines` from (used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797651)). However, the `InputForm` seems to have got a lot messier since then - I guess as they added more features and made it handle more cases...

Comment: I came across this by accident.  Try evaluating ``Experimental`Explore[Plot]``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another approach using `Nearest`, that's a bit different from Simon's:

```
plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}];
With[{nf = Nearest[Flatten[Cases[Normal[plot], Line[p_, ___] :> p, Infinity], 1]]},
   Show[plot, 
      Epilog -> 
         Dynamic[DynamicModule[{
            pt = First[nf[MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, {0, 0}]]], 
            scaled = Clip[MousePosition[{"GraphicsScaled", Graphics}, {0, 0}], {0, 1}]
            }, 
           {
            {If[scaled === None, {}, 
               {Lighter@Gray, Line[{
                   {Scaled[{scaled[[1]], 1}], Scaled[{scaled[[1]], 0}]}, 
                   {Scaled[{1, scaled[[2]]}], Scaled[{0, scaled[[2]]}]}
                   }]
               }]}, 
            {AbsolutePointSize[7], Point[pt], White, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pt]},
            Text[Style[NumberForm[Row[pt, ", "], {5, 2}], 12, Background -> White], Offset[{7, 0}, pt], {-1, 0}]}
         ]]
    ]
 ]
```

This was put together from example I had laying around.  (I don't like the free-floating drop-lines combined with the point tracking; either on its own feels fine.)

Comment: +1 I like how you get the `Nearest` point in the already generated graphic - it means for functions that are slow to numerically evaluate, you only need to evaluate them once for the plot.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one with the features you requested in comments:

```
locatorPlot[func_, r : {var_, __}, other___] :=
 LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[pos, (pos = {#, func /. var -> #}) & @@ # &],
   Column[{Plot[func, r, other], Dynamic@pos}],
   AutoAction -> True,
   Appearance ->
     Graphics[{Gray, Line @ {{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, -1}, {0, 1}}}},
       ImageSize -> Full]
 ]

locatorPlot[AiryAi[z], {z, -11, 5}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

---

Here is a rather clunky update to handle your new requests:

```
locatorPlot[func_List, r : {var_, __}, other___] :=
 DynamicModule[{pos, pos2},
  LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[pos, (pos = #; (pos2 = {#, First@Nearest[func /. var -> #, #2]}) & @@ #) &],
   Plot[func, r, other,
     Epilog ->
      {Text[\[GrayCircle], Dynamic@pos2], Text[Dynamic@pos2, Dynamic@pos2, {-1.2, 0}]}
   ],
   AutoAction -> True,
   Appearance -> 
     Graphics[{Gray, Line@{{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, -1}, {0, 1}}}}, ImageSize -> Full]
   ]
  ]

locatorPlot[{AiryAi[z], Sin[z]}, {z, -11, 5}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

Comment: +1 That's nice! It's different from the W|A behaviour, but that's ok. Can you emulate the way the W|A code jumps to the nearest graph in plots of more than one function? Try running `WolframAlpha["Ai(x), Bi(x)", {{"Plot", 1}, "Content"}]` to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Simon I am sorry, I don't have that function.  However, you are saying that the locator "snaps" to the nearest plot line, correct?

Comment: I forgot you had an old version. Yep, the gray lines follow the mouse position, but the circle and text snaps to the curves.

Comment: What ever you think is best. I'm just trying to get some nice, clean, flexible code that does something similar to the W|A stuff. I'll post my code which is close to the W|A behaviour, except for its handling of multiple graphs.

Comment: @Simon, oops, missed you own post.  I better take a quick look at that. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here's my version that behaves similarly to the Wolfram|Alpha output, except for its handling of multiple plots. In the W|A graphics, the circle and the text jump to the nearest curve, and disappear completely when the cursor is not over the graphics.
It would be nice to add in the missing functionality and maybe make the code more flexible.

```
WAPlot[fns_, range : {var_Symbol, __}] := 
 DynamicModule[{pos, fn = fns},
  If[Head[fn] === List, fn = First[Flatten[fn]]];
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pos, (pos = {var, fn} /. var -> #[[1]]) &], 
   Plot[fns, range, Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
    GridLines->Dynamic[{{#,Gray}}&/@MousePosition[{"Graphics",Graphics},None]]],
   AutoAction -> True, 
   Appearance -> Dynamic[Graphics[{Circle[pos, Scaled[.01]], 
       Text[Framed[Row[pos, ", "], RoundingRadius -> 5, 
         Background -> White], pos, {-1.3, 0}]}]]]]
```

Then, e.g.

```
WAPlot[{{AiryAi[x], -AiryAi[x]}, AiryBi[x]}, {x, -10, 2}]
```

[image]

---

Here's a new version that uses `MousePosition` instead of `LocatorPane` and steals Mr W's code to make the circle move to the nearest curve. 
The behaviour is now almost identical to the `WolframAlpha` output.

```
WAPlot[fns_, range : {var_Symbol, __}] := 
 DynamicModule[{fnList = Flatten[{fns}]}, Plot[fnList, range,
   GridLines -> 
    Dynamic[{{#, Gray}} & /@ MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}]],
   Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
   Epilog -> Dynamic[With[{mp = MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, None]},
      If[mp === None, {}, 
       With[{pos = {#1, First@Nearest[fnList /. var -> #1, #2]}& @@ mp},
        {Text[Style["\[EmptyCircle]", Medium, Bold], pos], 
         Text[Style[NumberForm[Row[pos, ", "], 2], Medium], pos, 
          {If[First[MousePosition["GraphicsScaled"]] < .5, -1.3, 1.3], 0}, 
          Background -> White]}]]]]
   ]]
```

The output looks very similar to the previous version so I won't post a screenshot.

Comment: Please tell me you didn't have this code when you asked the question, or I'm gonna shoot ya. ;-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I had it in separate pieces... just had to assemble it.  I guess it's a good thing we live on opposite sides of the planet!

Comment: I think you can adapt what I posted with `Nearest` etc., to make this functional.  Let me know if you have trouble.

Answer (score 2):

From Jens-Peer Kuska:

```
Manipulate[myPosition = p;
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, 
  Epilog -> {Point[p], Text[p, p + {0.4, 0}]}], {{p, {0, 0}}, 
  Locator}]
```

From Mark McClure:

```
labeledPointPlot[g_Graphics] := 
  Manipulate[
   Column[{Show[{g, Graphics@Point[pt]}], pt}], {pt, 
    Sequence @@ Transpose[PlotRange /. FullOptions[g]], Locator}];

labeledPointPlot[Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}]]
```

I found the origin of the code above, which I had previously written down:

http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/mathematica/10416/Mathematica-6-Graphics-Options

Comment: Hi Mr.W, I was more after the gray "crosshairs" than the locator showing the coordinates... I'm sorry that wasn't clear in the question. Also, the locator produced by `WolframAlpha` has [AutoAction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AutoAction.html) and follows the curve...

Comment: @Simon, I couldn't try that function so I didn't know.  See my new answer below.  I'll see what I can do about the actual lines.

Comment: @Simon, okay, I've got it.  Update in a minute.